# ES6 Promise does not get resolved with babel-polyfill in IE9

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-9, babeljs, es6-promise

I am transpiling my ES6 code with Webpack and the babel-polyfill dependency and trying make it work within IE9. It's working in IE10 and IE11 but for some reason my asynchronous Promise is not being resolved in IE9 and catches an error.

This is my Promise code:

```
function getJson(url) {
    // Return a new promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Do the usual XHR stuff
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);

        req.onload = () => {
            // This is called even on 404 etc, so check status
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                // Resolve the promise with the response text
                resolve(req.response);

            } else {
                // Otherwise reject with status text which will hopefully be a meaningful error
                reject(Error(req.statusText));
            }
        };
        // Handle network errors
        req.onerror = () => {
            reject(Error('Network Error'));
        };
        // Make the request
        req.send();
    });
}

export function loadAssets(url) {
    // then do our ajax event
    getJson(url)
        .then((response) => {
            // Convert string to array
            let parsedJson = JSON.parse(response);

            // dispatch receive assets
            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type: actionMessages.receiveAssets,
                assets: parsedJson
            });

            // there are a max of 20 assets per assetsdata file
            if (parsedJson.length < 20) {
                app.querySelector('footer').innerHTML = 'all assets loaded.';

                dispatcher.dispatch({
                    type: actionMessages.allAssetsLoaded
                });
            } else {
                app.querySelector('.cv-box').addEventListener('scroll', infiniteScroll);
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(error);

            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type: actionMessages.loadAssetsError
            });
        });
}
```

My transpiled Promise code:

```
function getJson(url) {
    // Return a new promise
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Do the usual XHR stuff
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);

        req.onload = function () {
            // This is called even on 404 etc, so check status
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                // Resolve the promise with the response text
                resolve(req.response);

            } else {
                // Otherwise reject with status text which will hopefully be a meaningful error
                reject(Error(req.statusText));
            }
        };
        // Handle network errors
        req.onerror = function () {
            reject(Error('Network Error'));
        };
        // Make the request
        req.send();
    });
}

function loadAssets(url) {
    // then do our ajax event
    getJson(url).then(function (response) {
        // Convert string to array
        var parsedJson = JSON.parse(response);

        // dispatch receive assets
        _dispatcher2.default.dispatch({
            type: actionMessages.receiveAssets,
            assets: parsedJson
        });

        // there are a max of 20 assets per assetsdata file
        if (parsedJson.length < 20) {
            app.querySelector('footer').innerHTML = 'all assets loaded.';

            _dispatcher2.default.dispatch({
                type: actionMessages.allAssetsLoaded
            });
        } else {
            app.querySelector('.cv-box').addEventListener('scroll', infiniteScroll);
        }
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log(error);

        _dispatcher2.default.dispatch({
            type: actionMessages.loadAssetsError
        });
    });
}
```

This is my webpack.config file:

```
require('babel-polyfill');

var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: '', // directory we currently in
    devtool: debug ? 'inline-sourcemap' : null,
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './js/client.js'], // Babel polyfill is required to make Promises work
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/, 
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        filename: 'client.min.js' 
    },
    watch: true,
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), // strip out duplicate code
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false}) // gets rid of sourcemaps, comments, etc
    ]
};
```

The error I receive in the console log is:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get rid of this error and make sure the promise gets resolved in IE9?

Comment: Your transpiled code still leaves in the Promise, which isn't supported in IE9. You most likely will need a promise polyfill.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am using this one: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/, its defined in the global scope of the transpiled Promise code file, hence my promise is currently working in IE10 and IE11, just doesn't resolve the promise in IE9.

Comment: Do you have a line number for that error in the transpiled output? If I had to guess, your issue is that XHR2 is only supported on IE>=10, so your `.onload` will never run, and thus the promise will never resolve. You'll probably have to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange or a separate AJAX library wrapper.

Comment: You were right. I used Axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), which made it possible for me to remove the entire getJson function and it solved my problem.